# NancyFX Post - Bind to Object with List Parameter

Tags: nancy

I am using Nancy and I have created a basic model with a List property on it.  When I use the below GET method I get the expected JSON output.  However when I try to POST back the same JSON I end up with an object with and empty list of strings.  I created two properties just to verify that my issue wasn't because of instantiating the DataPoints parameter to a new List in the constructor.  Does anyone have any ideas on why this isn't returning properly?

JSON Object Returned from Initial Get

```
{
   "dataPoints": [
      "0",
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4"
   ],
   "dataPoints2": [
      "0",
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4"
   ]
}
```

JSON Object Returned from Post:

```
{
   "dataPoints": [],
   "dataPoints2": []
}
```

Class:

```
public class BasicModel
{
  private List<string> _dataPoints;
  public List<string> DataPoints
  {
    get
    {
      if (_dataPoints == null)
        {
          _dataPoints = new List<string>();
        }
        return _dataPoints;
    }
    set
    {
      _dataPoints = value;
    }
  }

  public List<string> DataPoints2 { get; set; }

  public BasicModel()
  {
    DataPoints2 = new List<string>();
  }

  public BasicModel(int idx)
  {
    DataPoints2 = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < idx; i++)
    {
      DataPoints.Add(i.ToString());
      DataPoints2.Add(i.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Get Method:

```
Get["/basicModel/{idx}"] = parameters =>
{
    int idx = Convert.ToInt32(parameters["idx"].ToString());
    BasicModel m = new BasicModel(idx);

    return Negotiate
        .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        .WithModel(m)
        .WithView("default");
};
```

Post Method:

```
Post["/basicmodel"] = parameters =>
{
    BasicModel m = new BasicModel();
    this.BindTo(m);

    return Negotiate
        .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        .WithModel(m)
        .WithView("default");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into a [know issue](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1383) with `BindTo` create a new instance even though you give one.

You should be able use `Bind` instead of `BindTo` though and have bind return a new object:

```
Post["/basicmodel"] = parameters =>
{
   BasicModel m = this.Bind();

   return Negotiate
      .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)
      .WithModel(m)
      .WithView("default");
};
```